# Home computer can't keep internet connection with wireless usb adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, adapter

I did some work on a computer recently that had problems keeping an internet connection.  Here's what happened.  I turned on the computer and there was no wireless connection.  After resetting the USB cable that connected the Wireless G USB Adapter (old linksys that still had the light blue on the box) to the computer the connection came back but only for a moment.  I ran the windows connection diagnostics wizard from IE and it was able to find the connection.  The connection held for about an hour and during that hour I updated Malwarebytes and ran a scan, it was clean.  The virus scanner also turned up clean.  After this was done Windows lost the connection.  After a Windows reboot the connection was found immediately and it held the remainder of the time I was there.  Given that this has been an issue for the client for some time I suggested purchasing a PCI wireless adapter.  I'm under the assumption that there is a problem with the (old) wireless USB adapter or possibly even the cable it is attached to.  Possibly not enough power?

In the end what I want to know is what else could be the problem?

Edit: I should note that this is related to a desktop not a laptop.  If that matters at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, usb wireless adapters are really hit or miss. Sometimes they just will not work with a certain laptop, but will work fine with others.  I would say get a PCI wireless adapter - they are pretty much the same price as a usb but you will get no reliability issues and probably better reception.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  That's what I was thinking too.  I noticed that when the USB adapter was working it had a very strong signal.  Plus, like you, I've noticed that USB adapters are a hit or miss.